# Install and create a Kubernetes cluster on lxc proxmox

Tags: docker, kubernetes, lxc, proxmox

I would like to know who tried to install and create a Kubernetes cluster inside LXC proxmox.

Which steps should I follow to realize that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use below articles to get the desired result:
[Run kubernetes inside LXC container](https://medium.com/@kvaps/run-kubernetes-in-lxc-container-f04aa94b6c9c) or [Run Kubernetes as Proxmox container](https://gist.github.com/kvaps/25f730e0ec39dd2e5749fb6b020e71fc)

To summarize above articles you should perform next steps:

1) Add `overlay driver` for docker.

```
echo overlay >> /etc/modules
```

2) Add more privileges to container by modifying container config

```
lxc.apparmor.profile: unconfined
lxc.cap.drop: 
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow: a
lxc.mount.auto: proc:rw sys:rw
```

3) Use shared filesystem to /etc/rc.local

```
echo '#!/bin/sh -e
mount --make-rshared /' > /etc/rc.local
```

4) Init cluster using kubeadm